# British English Reference Check

Tags: discussion

What would be the best reference for a writer who follows British English in his writing style? are there any online tools that have proofread feature for the same? or a reliable dictionary to use that could be available online and free of charge

Comment: Hi, Zeynep. There is no easy way for you to have known this, but requests for resources (such as reliable style guides or other reference works) are the purview of English Language & Usage's Meta site, not its main site. Accordingly, I have voted to move the question to EL&U Meta.

Comment: It will depend if you're writing academic texts, fiction, journalism, for a specific audience, or something else.